# NSArray, how get items based on a property's value

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have  NSMutableArray which contains a list of people , now I need to get a list of all people where gender = male, how can I do that? should I get into NSPredicates to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy this `NSArray` category to to somewhere in your code

```
@implementation NSArray (My)

-(NSArray*)arrayWithPredicate:(BOOL(^)(id obj))predicate {
    NSMutableArray* objs = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id o, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (predicate(o)) {
            [objs addObject:o];
        }
    }];

    return objs;
}

@end
```

Then where you need to get the male ones:

```
NSArray* males = [people arrayWithPredicate:^BOOL(id obj) {
    // Gender check 
}];
```

The advantage over `NSPredicate` is that you don't have to use a literal string to specify the criteria (quite a mess if the criteria is complex).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use like this,

```
NSArray *filtered = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.gender == %@", @"male"]];
NSLog(@"%@",filtered);
```